# Using Calendar Function To Substitute Sleep / Wait Function in Java

Tags: java, calendar, wait, sleep

So one day, i wonder if i can make a simple program which wait for a few second before initializing the rest of the program code. My first idea at that time is by using Calendar function like this ;

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class NewMain {

static int count = 0 ;
static int time = 0 ;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    time = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    count = time +1;
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(count);

    while (time < count){
        time = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

The idea is when the value of `time` become greater than `count`, the rest of the program will be executed. However, when i tried this code the program keeps going even after the value of `time` is greater than
`count`.

I know this is a bad code because it's a waste of resources and there's `sleep` or `wait` function which works like this, but i'm curious why that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Calendar` object represents a fixed point in time. Its fields do not update every time the time changes, so repeated calls to `cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)` will always return the same value. Because of this, `time < count` is *always* `true`. You'll need to get a new `Calendar` instance each iteration to make this work:

```
while (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) < count) { ... }
```

Which isn't a great idea performance-wise.

Comment: Ah, i see. So i need to make another object of Calendar inside the loop to make it works. It really is not the best way to make a program. Well, thanks for the answer.